# Transplanting periwinkle

Tags: transplanting, outdoor, yard

I have plenty of periwinkle (probably *Vinca minor*, or possibly *V. major*) in my back yard. I will soon attend to building a storage shed there. I would have to clear periwinkle for the shed ground. I would like to transplant that periwinkle to a sloping part of my front grassy/weedy yard that causes me headaches when moving. How do I perform this operation and when is the best time to do that? I am talking about western Pennsylvania.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to dig out the Vinca with roots attached in order to tranplant it, and you should only do that when the winter is over and the ground is not frozen. If the area you want to transplant to dries out frequently during spring/early summer and you are unable to irrigate it frequently until they are established, it's probably best to pot up rooted sections, cut them back to an inch or so and let them grow sufficiently to form a good root system before planting them out. If you transplant to the ground immediately, ensure you have dug over the area where you want to move them to first, cut back the top growth to about 1 or 2 inches, then water in well after planting. You will obviously lose the flowers this year, but they may produce a few later on.

Comment: In springs, I have been lazy before and just mowed mine near the edge of the bed.  A TON of it just roots in the lawn on its own!  It should be a relatively easy transplant.    You could probably just pull up a lot of it, turn it into the new soil, and keep it moist.

Comment: Vinca throws out quite long stems - where the end is in contact with soil, it will form roots  over time, that's why  its in your lawn.

Comment: All right, I will definitely heed the advices and try it out. I think the main guessing for me will be to estimate when the snow/freeze will not come back. I will report on the results in due course.

Answer (score 0):

I have now performed the transplant(ation), the first for me. I shaved off about 1-2 inch of grassy new location soil, and brought in dug out Vinca and placed it there. If the lumps were with complete root, it took root in the new location, if I skimmed, it did not take root. This was done last Summer and I see, majority of the area is still covered, but it does not look as perfectly healthy as where it came from. It did have a few flowers in the new spot. I think this year will show me how things are going. Vinca is a creepy crawly, and I hope that will happen so at least the sloping parts of my front yard get covered. My concern is that the new location gets too much sun in comparison to the back yard shady area where it thrives.